Solution of $(-\Delta)^{s/2}u=f$ and Homogeneous Sobolev space.
I read about the homogeneous Sobolev space $\dot{L}_s^p:=\dot{L}_s^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in the book  L. Grafakos, Modern Fourier Analysis, 3. ed (Springer, New York, NY, 2014) And the following question came up to me. First, some definitions:
Consider $1<p<\infty$. Let $s\in \mathbb{R}$. The homogeneous Sobolev space is defined by $$\dot{L}_s^p=\left\{u\in \mathcal{S}'/\mathcal{P}\colon \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(|\xi|^s\widehat{u}\right)\in \dot{L}^p\right\}$$
$$\dot{L}^p=\left\{u\in \mathcal{S}'/\mathcal{P}\colon \text{ every equivalence class contains a unique representative in } L^p\right\}$$
($u\equiv v$ if $u-v\in \mathcal{P}$). The space $\dot{L}^p$ has a norm $\left\|f+P\right\|_{\dot{L}^p}=\left\|f\right\|_{\dot{L}^p}=\left\|f\right\|_{L^p}$ with $P$ a polynomial.
Question. If $f\in \dot{L}^p$, $(-\Delta)^{s/2}u=f$ has a unique solution in the space $\dot{L}_s^p$?
My attempt: Formally, $(-\Delta)^{s/2}u=f$ is $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(|\xi|^s\widehat{u}\right)=f$, then, $u=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{|\xi|^{s}}\widehat{f}\right)$ solves the equation  and $u\in \dot{L}_s^p$ since $f\in \dot{L}^p$, but, the singularity of the function $1/|\xi|^s$ disturbs me.

The fact that $\hat{f}(0) =0$ otherwise the PDE has no solution probably helps sonehow.

Since OP works modulo polynomials, there are no trouble. In this case, the Sobolev spaces are the closure/completion of Schwartz functions whose Fourier transform is supported away from 0, so you define everything by density.

Thanks. But I imagine that $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(1/|\xi|^s)$ only makes sense for certain values of $s$?
